# Restore delphi form windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-xe

I have an application written in Delphi XE and I can maximize and minimize using Windows XP without problems. Using Windows 7 I can't restore the application after minimize it. I click the taskbar and the window don't appears. I have to kill the application using the system administrator. Any clues to find the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a brand new project or does it come from an older Delphi version?

Comment: The project comes from Delphi 7

Comment: Add `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;` after `Application.Initialize` in your poject DPR file and it should be OK

Comment: Tell us what special/different you do with the main window or application handle in your program? I ask because the standard Delphi application does not show this behavior.

Comment: Do you create your main form using Application.CreateForm call?

Comment: No, that was exactly the problem. The application don't have main form. After Application.Run a form is created and used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alter your project according to

```
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
```

Comment: Now the application minimizes in the bottom left of the screen but not appears in the taskbar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, I don't use this operation

Comment: sounds like MDIChild behavior ... but a child without a parent?

Comment: I found the problem. The main form wasn't create properly in the dpr. Tranks for the help

Comment: @whosrdaddy I can see it in the comments, didn't see it before posting, what can be done?

Comment: bummi - AFAICS your answer is posted about 2 minutes before @whos's comment. My guess would be, he probably explains his upvote reason, not that he wants to take credit.